# Prove that every edge of a graph which is not in the breadth first search tree joins vertices that are at most one level apart

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

This is the second part of a question that I'm trying to solve/prove. This is the full question.

**Suppose at some stage in the breadth-first search algorithm the rooted tree has height h. Show that the next vertex added to the tree must be at height h or h+1.**

**Also prove that every edge of the graph which is not in the breadth first search tree joins vertices that are at most one level apart.**

Also I'm using this algorithm for breadth first search:

Let G = (V, E) be a graph with vertices ordered V = ($v_1$, $v_2$, ..., $v_n$). Let Q be an initially empty queue.

1. Insert $v_1$ at the back of Q and mark $v_1$ as visited.
2. While Q is non-empty

   - Remove the vertex at the front of Q, set this vertex as v
   - For vertices $v_{i1}$, $v_{i2}$, ..., $v_{ik}$ adjacent to v and ordered by $i1$ < $i2$ ... < $ik$, for $v_{ij}$, if $v_{ij}$ is unvisited then: insert $v_{ij}$ at the end of Q and mark it as visited and add {v, $v_{ij}$} to $E_t$, where $E_t$ is the edges in the tree.

For the first part of the question I have: when a vertex is removed at the start of the queue $Q$ and set to $v$, it will be the depth of the tree or 1 less than the depth of tree. The vertices adjacent to $v$ added to the queue $Q$ will be one deeper than $v$ and thus at the height $h$ or $h+1$.

However for the second part I am unsure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a breadth-first tree, the level of a vertex always equals its shortest distance to the root vertex.

For two vertices joined by an edge, the difference in their distances to the root vertex can be at most $1$.